# How to create a dataframe from numpy arrays?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to create a matrix / DataFrame with the numbers stored in 2 variables

```
x = np.linspace(0,50)
y = np.exp(x)
```

and I would like them to look like this:

```
x    |     y
___________________
0    |     1.0...
1    |     2.77...             
2    |     7.6...                      
...  |     ...             
50   |     5.18e+21...
```

I would like it to be in a `DataFrame` so I can work with it with the `pandas` library.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `pandas`:

You can issue

```
>>> xs = np.arange(51)                                                                                                 
>>> ys = np.exp(xs)
```

to get the x and y values and then build your dataframe with

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'x': xs, 'y': ys})
>>> df                                                                                                                 
     x             y
0    0  1.000000e+00
1    1  2.718282e+00
2    2  7.389056e+00
3    3  2.008554e+01
...
```

In this case, you can also use the x-values as the index of a series without losing any information.

```
>>> index = pd.RangeIndex(0, 51, name='x')                                                                             
>>> exps = pd.Series(data=np.exp(index), index=index, name='y')                                                        
>>> exps                                                                                                               
x
0     1.000000e+00
1     2.718282e+00
2     7.389056e+00
3     2.008554e+01
...
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

---

Without `pandas`:

Consider if you truly need a dataframe or series. You could just leave it at

```
>>> xs = np.arange(51)                                                                                                 
>>> ys = np.exp(xs)
```

and then index into `ys` with the integers `0`, `1`, `2`, ... to get the values of `exp(0)`, `exp(1)`, `exp(2)`, ...

Answer (score 4):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y})
```

Change the key in the dictionary to your desired column name.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = np.linspace(0,50)
df['y'] = np.exp(df['x'])
```

Answer (score 3):

Assign column names and set columns in the mean time :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x" : x , "y" : y})
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0,50)
y = np.exp(x)

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make a list of tuples and pass it to the `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(i, np.exp(i)) for i in np.linspace(0,50)], columns=['x', 'y'])
```

**Output**

```
x        y
0  1.000000e+00
1  2.718282e+00
2  7.389056e+00
...
```

Comment: Besides being inefficient because of the loop, `np.arange(50)` does not produce the same output as `np.linspace(0, 50)`.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `[np.concatenate][1]`.

So for your example, the code would be

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,50)
y = np.exp(x)
z = np.concatenate((x.reshape(1,-1),y.reshape(1,-1))).T
print(z.shape)
# (2,50)
```